# Xamarin.Forms video renderer restarts

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-videoview

I have my own Xamarin.Forms project which I got the video to play but everytime the video is minimized(Home button / lock screen) the video restarts at the beginning. The video plays fine on IOS/recovers fine.

Ive attempted to capture the onPause / OnResume/Onrestart methods in the mainactivity and none of them provide the instance of "videoPlayer"OR "videoPlayerRenderer" with a position higher than 0.  So I went and downloaded the provided demo from Xamarin located here [Link to MS DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/customrenderers-videoplayerdemos/).  This has the SAME behavior as my modified project(copy/pasted this code anyways).

I have attempted to set the following modes on my MainActivity in the demo Launchmode "LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask" and have attempted "ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation"

All my tests were run on a Android emulator and also my physical S8+ running OS Android 9.0(pie) in both debug and release versions.  I checked my developer settings and nothing is killing the activity "Dont keep Activities" as I saw that in a previous StackOverflow question.

Comment: Does your phone have enough memory? When it runs out of memory, the android system will timely recycle the application memory.

Comment: It said on DDMS that I had plenty of HEAP space.  Is there a better way to look for this information? My device log on my phone streams way to many messages per second for me to read anything off of it.

Comment: You can try to open `Help`-->`Xamarin`-->`Open Logs...`

Comment: Ive checked the logs and there is nothing that suggests memory issues additionally it does it with the naked MS project.  Is this a backgrounding thing in Android 9.0+?

Comment: Android always has this recycling mechanism.

Comment: Ok so ill have additional logs tonight but it looks that even while my video is playing im getting the surfaceview destroyed.  Im trying to investigate why the surface would be destroyed prior to the renderer finishing.

Comment: Ok so just to reiterate.  I have tried it on 3 devices 1 virtual and 2 physical.  On Android it is expected behavior that when a view renderer gets minimized that the view will restart at the beginning? I downloaded the sample above and ran it as is and it causes my Android device videos to start from the beginning.  This is not the same behavior on IOS with the same code.

Comment: Confirmed this code is outdated as when you deploy in both debug/release the phone even tells you its outdated.  This sample is not longer a viable solution as it loops the video back to the beginning when being returned from any other activity